# Listing files between certain number range in R

Tags: r

I have a list of jpgs in a folder that are named according to the following convention:

Site_transect_date_image number

e.g. South_1_20220322_0001

The image numbers are padded with zeroes (e.g. 0001, 0010, 0100, 1000). I want to list files with image numbers only from 0450-1700 and then copy them over into a new directory.

I've tried this code:

```
gettransect <- function(v) {
  pat <- paste0("(", paste0(v, collapse="|"), ")")
  return(pat)
}

transect <- c(0450:1700) 
pat <- paste0("^South_1_20220322_", gettransect(transect), ".jpg$")

filestocopy <- as.data.frame(list.files(pattern=pat))
```

However, as the image numbers are padded with zeroes, it only lists the files from 1000 to 1700 and doesn't recognise files 0450-0999. How do I overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

You can zero-pad numbers using `stringr::str_pad()`. In your code, you would define `transect` as:

```
library(stringr)

transect <- str_pad(450:1700, width = 4, pad = "0")
```

Comment: thanks @zephryl - I added the zero padding to that line of code and it's worked perfectly!